# Command line SVN Copy Trunk to Tag: while making the copied external folder a revision number and not revision HEAD

Tags: svn

I am looking to perform an svn copy via command line (no tortoise svn) that performs what is mentioned in the title.  This is to be done automatically(Another process will call the .bat that performs the command line SVN functionality).

This is the command I use right now

svn.exe copy "path\trunk" "path\tags.

It does an exact copy of the trunk(as it should).  The only thing I want different is: in the tags folder, I want the External folder to say "revision 12345" rather than "revision HEAD".

NOTE:  revision 12345 = the HEAD revision in the trunk at the time of the copy.  This is beneficial if we ever need to look at tag in the future.  We can see the exact version of the External folder rather than "HEAD".

In the past this was manually done after making the tag and then using Tortoise SVN -> branch/merge

Answer (score 0):

> n the tags folder, I want the External folder to say "revision 12345" rather than "revision HEAD"

You can't do it with plain copy. Copy is **exact copy** of source, using PEG-revision in definition you'll change property of external's parent

Comment: So for SVN command line "PEG-revision" is the only option ?  And it modifies properties of the parent directory ?  Hmmm if so, I may scratch this idea.  Thanks for your input Badger !

Comment: @user3555181 - Well, /tags is readonly only by convention. you can create draft of tag by server-side copy and fix it with additional commit